# How do Routers share a key when using Symmetric Cryptography?

Tags: router, key-exchange

When a client connects to a router (standard home router) how is the key distributed to the client? If the key is sent across the network, can not someone sniff and see the key? If the key is not sent across the network, is it generated via the routers access password (the password used to access the network)?

Comment: It's unclear what you're referring to here. Are you asking about WPA2 on WiFi, or something else?

Comment: Seems like he is asking about WiFi, which is probably WPA2. So, OP, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access

Comment: [Key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange)

Answer (score 2):

When a client connects to a WiFi network using WPA2 (802.11i), using standard password authentication, it uses the password as a Pre-Shared Key (PSK). In practice, the PSK is passed through a key-derivation function (KDF), based on SHA1, which then creates the Pairwise Master Key (PMK) that is used to derive further keys for communication. The PMK is a long-term key used to set up all connections between clients (e.g. phones, laptops) and the access point (e.g. router).

The access point (e.g. router) knows the PSK, and therefore knows the PMK that is derived from it.  Since a client connecting with the correct password will derive that same PMK, they both have access to a shared secret key without needing to transmit any data between them. This allows them to securely initiate a handshake when the client connects.

Since the PMK is a long-term key (potentially in use for years), it should be used to encrypt as little information as possible, so as to prevent long-term traffic capture from aiding theoretical cryptanalysis attacks. As such, the keys used for actually encrypting and verifying the authenticity of the traffic are derived separately. This is done using a 4-way handshake.

[image: 4-way handshake for WPA2]

The access point provides the client with a unique nonce value, called ANonce (access point nonce), which is used to prevent replay attacks. The client generates its own nonce value, called SNonce (station nonce), then combines the PMK, ANonce, SNonce, and MAC addresses of the client and AP. This combined string is fed into a hash function. This forms the Pairwise Transient Key (PTK) that is used for the actual bulk encryption.

The PTK itself is not one single key, but instead split into five separate keys: the KCK, used for EAPOL authentication (ignore this, it's only used for WPA2 Enterprise); the KEK, used for encrypting extra data in the handhsake; a temporal key (TK), used for traffic encryption; and a pair of authenticity keys used for generating message integrity codes (MICs) for the transmit (TX) and receive (RX) directions.

The client sends the SNonce value to the access point, plus an authenticity record. The authenticity record is called a MIC by the specification, but this is somewhat of a misnomer - normally we'd call it a Message Authenticity Code (MAC) or Message Authenticity & Integrity Code (MAIC) since the point is to ensure that the traffic was authentic in nature and not tampered with. You can think of the MIC like a HMAC. In this case, the MIC is generated over the SNonce value, using the RX MIC key. When the AP receives the SNonce value, it combines the given SNonce with the ANonce it previous sent, plus the other information needed to generate the PMK. It generates the PMK, then calculates the same MIC that the client did, over the SNonce, using the RX MIC from the PMK. If the MIC is valid, then the AP now knows that the password the user entered was correct - if it wasn't, the PMKs wouldn't match up, which would mean the MIC wouldn't match up either.

At this point both the client and the access point have a shared PMK and can communicate. There's one last step, though. Because WiFi networks need to be able to broadcast traffic, and support multicast, rather than just unicast streams between the AP and the client, there needs to be a separate key for that. Remember, the PTK is the *pairwise* key, meaning "between two devices". In order to allow for multicast and broadcast, the last stage of the handshake establishes the Group Temporal Key (GTK). Since at this point in the handshake the client device is authenticated and both the client and AP have knowledge of the PTK, the AP can just encrypt the GTK using the Temporal Key using the KEK (Key Encryption Key) mentioned earlier. The message containing the encrypted GTK is also protected by a MIC to prevent tampering.

To sum up:

- When the client authenticates, it turns the password (PSK) into a key (PMK) that is used in the handshake process. The first part of the handshake is used to build a Pairwise Temporal Key (PTK) that is used for authentication, later parts of the handshake, encryption of network traffic, and message authenticity checking.
- The server and client use unique nonce values to prevent replay attacks.
- If the client provides the wrong password (PSK), the wrong PMK will be derived, and the client and access points will end up with different PTKs. If this happens, the message authenticity check will fail and the client cannot authenticate.
- Once the client has authenticated to the server, they both know the same PTK. This allows them to encrypt traffic and authenticate that the messages were not tampered with in transit.
- In order to support multicast and broadcast traffic, the Key Encryption Key (KEK) from the PTK is used to share a Group Temporal Key (GTK).
- The PKT's Temporal Key (TK) allows for encryption of traffic between the client and the AP, and the PTK's TX and RX keys allow for authenticity verification of that unicast traffic.
- The GTK's Group Temporal Encryption Key (GTEK) allows for encryption of broadcast and multicast traffic, and the GTK's TX key is used to validate the authenticity of that traffic.

Answer (score -1):

Any type of key exchange that has to be done in an open setting works like this:

1. The initiator creates an *asymmetric key pair* (**public/private key cryptography**)
2. Initiator sends their **public key** in the clear and open to the recipient. It doesn't matter if its intercepted because its only good for sending the initiator encrypted messages.
3. The recipient generates a nice strong *symmetric key* (or **password** but better). He encrypts this password with the **initiators public key**. Only the initiator can decrypt it. He then sends it back to the initiator fully encrypted.
4. The initiator receives his encrypted message and decrypts it with his **private key** to find the **shared key/password**!
5. Now both parties can use some **nice strong fast** *symmetric algorithm* (like **AES**) with their **shared password or key** *and this channel of communication will be private.*

Comment: If OP is asking about WiFi, this is not how WPA2 works at all. You're describing a basic hybrid cryptosystem, but WPA2 is a PSK system that doesn't use asymmetric cryptography.

Comment: And this isn't even how TLS works.