# How is WPA-PSK authentication done?

Tags: authentication, wifi, wpa2, wpa2-psk

When I try connecting to wireless networks (**with no RADIUS server**), I enter the password and it goes through an authentication process. After the station successfully connects to the access point, a 4-way handshake is done to generate PTK, GMK to encrypt the traffic.

In this case, I want to know how the authentication is done. I wonder if there are some protocols in wireless network authentication (generally in home networks, preshared-key settings).

**I'm not talking about the 4-way handshake.** Though I searched for WPA-PSK authentication, all I could find were posts explaining the 4-way handshake. In this post https://www.wifi-professionals.com/2019/01/4-way-handshake, I want to know what is going on in the authentication management frames. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLlcz.png) is the image in the post what I am curious about.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/255862/86735

Answer (score 1):

IEEE 802.11 standard defines two types of authentication:

- Open System
- Shared Key

Joining a client to the access point includes four steps:

- Authentication (Request)
- Authentication (Response)
- Association Request
- Association Response

[WPA, WPA2, and WPA3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access) are the three security certification programs developed by the **Wi-Fi Alliance**. This type of authentication comprises:

- 802.11 open system authentication
- Association request/response
- WPA authentication/key exchange

For  more information see [this post](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55790/why-do-we-have-authentication-before-association-in-802-11).